# How can I load a web page inside of a jQuery dialog box?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am designing a wordpress template, and I would like to use jQuery ui to display each of the calendar links in a dialog box, when they are clicked.

What I want, is when someone clicks on a link in the wordpress calendar, the content will load in the dialog box, and display over the calendar.

I would appreciate any help on this, thanx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to load a seperate page you can use:

```
$("#youDiv").load("yourURL").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    bgiframe: true,
    width: 450
});
$("#youDiv").dialog('open');
```

Comment: How could I get it to find certain elements inside of the selected element? Say for instance, I would like to find all the links inside of the youDiv element, how could I go about doing that?

Comment: $("a","#youDiv") will give all the links once the page is loaded inside the div.